# How to retrieve all checked checkboxes?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I defined some checkboxes with Angular Material Checkbox component: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

```
<div>
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="authors" class="authors-checkboxes" *ngFor="let author of authors" [value]=author.id>{{ author.name }}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

And a FormGroup

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(article.id),
  timestamp: new FormControl(article.timestamp),
  title: new FormControl(article.title),
  chapo: new FormControl(article.chapo),
  body: new FormControl(article.body),
  bodyStyle: new FormControl(article.bodyStyle),
  author: new FormControl(article.author),
  authors: new FormControl(article.authors),
  authors2: new FormControl(article.authors2),
  date: new FormControl(article.date),
  readingTime: new FormControl(article.readingTime),
  pictures: new FormControl(),
  status: new FormControl(),
  mainPicture: new FormControl(article.mainPicture),
  mainPictureFile: new FormControl(article.mainPictureFile),
  position: new FormControl(article.position)
});
```

What's the best way to get all clicked checkboxes? I want to gather all selected authors.

I was considering doing it with *document.getElementsByClassName* and *forEach*, but have the feeling it's not the good approach.

```
const authorsCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("authors-checkboxes");
console.log(authorsCheckboxes);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(authorsCheckboxes, function(authorCheckbox) {
  console.log(authorCheckbox);
  console.log(authorCheckbox.value);
});
```

Comment: How do you create your formGroup? And yes, getElementsByClassName is just wrong

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated the question

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't retrieve check boxes, you retrieve the data they are bound to.

Comment: Hopefully you also realize that you cannot bind a string value of `id` to a boolean value of whether or not a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Add `isSelected` property to the author class and use two-way binding on the checkbox. You can then filter on the author list based on selected status.

```
<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let author of authors" [(ngModel)]="author.isSelected"></mat-checkbox>
```

Stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/mxvrpgjvnba

`authors.filter(a=>a.isSelected);`

**Option 2**

Use the `change` event of the checkbox to keep track of selected authors. You could keep selected authors in an array and add/remove on change event.

`change: EventEmitter<MatCheckboxChange>`

**Option 3**

Alternatively, you can look at Selection lists:

https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists

Demo that shows selected options:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmxjxxaoode?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.ts

Comment: Option 2 is not really an option in Angular - it was built for Option 1. Option 2 will be  unreliable and Option 3 should not be necessary. Thus Option 1 is all that should be presented here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I like the Option 3. I didn't know the selection list component. I am going to try it, it will be much easier and clean I think

Answer (score 1):

I think people in general struggle with something like this because they are very used to doing data binding the old-fashioned, manual way. To be successful in Angular, the old ways must be forgotten, and the new ways adopted. Otherwise you'll end up with the dreaded `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

**Angular handles your data binding for you.**

When you use `[(ngModel)]`, the syntax contains a two-way data binding. The `[]` indicate a binding from your data to the control. the `()` indicate a binding from the control back to your data. `[(ngModel)]` is implemented for all of the standard HTML form controls.

When a box is checked, the expression in the `ngModel` is run to set the property on the model class. It also works in reverse - when you change the property on the underlying data class, it will be reflected on the HTML form.

Thus, we have two realizations:

1. Generally speaking, you do not manipulate HTML elements directly - Angular does this for you.
2. Keeping the view and the data model in sync no longer requires manual code wiring.

**What to do?**

There is really one option here. You need to have an object to map to whether or not the author is selected:

```
authors = [ { author: {...}, isSelected: false} ];
```

Then, your `ngFor` will use this as its input:

```
<div>
  <mat-checkbox class="authors-checkboxes" *ngFor="let item of authors" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected">{{ item.author.name }}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**Note also** that Angular does not support mixing `ngModel` and `FormGroup`. If you need to use `FormGroup`, you should proceed that direction, but you'll still need to create the intermediate class to contain the information on whether a given author is selected.  See more - https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 0):

Try by using a filter function

```
//if value is a boolean if not use a comparation.
authorsCheckboxes.filter(x => x.value)
```